# Installing composer library (FOSUserBundle) error - parsing version constraint

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I'm trying to install sf2 library - FOSUserBundle - using composer. However after running cmd command `php composer.phar require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle '~2.0@dev'` just like it says in the documentation, I get `could not parse version constraint "'~2.0@dev'"` error.

What's wrong here? Composer.phar is in its default state, I didn't change anything there.

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

EDIT. Update doesn't work either, it says that FOSUserBundle library is not installed and will be ignored, and after a couple of minutes it says that parameters.yml.dist is not found, but it's there, well...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue... I just substituted master for the version constraint and it was happy.

Maybe not the best solution but it solves the issue for the moment.

-- EDIT: That seemed to work but then failed on a composer update... changed the composer.json to @dev and that is now working